# Two levels of 'and'

Tags: classical-latin, word-comparison, conjunction, finnish

What I am looking for is best illustrate by an example, so please excuse the detour.
In Finnish there are two words for "and": "ja" and "sekä".
When used together, "ja" joins things on a lower level and "sekä" on a higher one in the following sense.
Suppose there are two couples, one consisting of Marcus and Maria and the other one of Lucius and Lucia.
If I want to invite both couples to party, I could list them in Finnish as "Marcus ja Maria sekä Lucius ja Lucia".
Here one level of "and" joins two people into a couple and the other one joins the two couples.
This structure emphasizes that I am speaking of two couples, not just listing four individuals.
I am not familiar with a similar device in English so my example is drawn from Finnish.

Are there two levels of "and" available in Latin in a similar fashion?
I am tempted to use either one of these despite never seeing them in action:

1. Marcus et Maria atque Lucius et Lucia
2. Marcus Mariaque et Lucius Luciaque

But is such a construction with two levels of "and" attested in classical (or perhaps later) Latin?
What is the idiomatic choice?

---

(The core question in Finnish in case someone searches for it: Miten erotetaan 'ja' ja 'sekä' latinaksi?)

Comment: (may I ask, what the Latin for a sheet-bend is?  [ref. the insignia on yr flag])

Comment: @Hugh I have no idea. But you can always ask a separate question about that. There's no question too small.

Comment: I wonder if you could perhaps use *velut … sic* in a pinch, e.g. *velut Marcum et Mariam, sic Lucium et Luciam invitabo ad convivium* – this is how we do it in German (*so* + *wie* = *sowie*), but in Latin *velut* + *sic* usually is correlative.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel A quick search produces "velut in cantu et fidibus quae ἁρμονία dicitur: sic ex corporis totius natura et figura varios motus cieri tamquam in cantu sonos" (Cicero, Tusculanae Disputationes), "uelut ante deuictarum gentium Numantinus et Isauricus, ita Sergius Orata et Licinius Muraena" (L. Iunius Moderatus Columella, De Re Rustica), "quippe q non constat aliter quam duabus c et u, b velut vel k quod esse q vides muti soni; q velut et u, c quoque et uu plenius quod postmodum 
sic in unam q" (Terentianus Maurus, De Litt.). Perhaps something like that could indeed work.

Comment: @Joonas llmavirta: In English "and also" would divide the two pairs of nouns. "I invited A and B and also C and D.". These words are not the same: "and" is a conjunction; "also" is an adverb--"in the same manner"; "in addition"; "as well". Further, it prevents the clumsy repetition: ".....A and B and C and D.". The second pair may be of a lower priority: "I invited the Prime Minister and his wife and also a minister and his wife." You would not say: "I invited a minister and his wife and also the Prime...". The Latin is "necnon" = "and also", an adverb.

Comment: @tony In Finnish you can do this with two conjunctions, and according to the answer also in Latin. An adverb like "also" is a workaround but not quite the same as what Finnish and Latin can do without any sense of priority.

Comment: @Joonas llmavirta: There is only one ex. of this use in Glosbe--uses of necnon; but, without attestation. Interesting is "Dominus vobiscum, et cum spiritu tuo" = "God be with you and your spirit". The ICEL (International Community on English in the Liturgy) is considering changing this translation to "....and also your sprit.".

Comment: @vectory Which half of each couple is listed first is not of much importance for this question. And I don't think the tradition of "ladies first" applies to listing couples, but that is beside the point. I have actually paid attention to gender balance in some questions. // More importantly, please refrain from etymological speculation, especially in connection with a question that is not about etymology. If you have a question about the etymological connections of *et*, they should go into a separate new question.

Comment: You missed the point: "*The change of a commitative adposition "with" to a coordinating conjunction "and" is not unusual and often seen in the languages of the world*"([1](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/35944/22504)). That's typology, not etymology per se. It's stochastic not speculative, because I don't draw any conclusion. I just mentioned it for your purview. // I insist that a correct translation has to take etymology into account, if possible. It's certainly not forbidden. More over, even a wrong etymology (Mari-ja) can lead to a correct translation, yea? You can hold it any way.

Comment: @vectory That's indeed a relevant remark. I just didn't know what exactly you were referring to in the linked post. It's worth checking whether a similar effect has been reached in attested Latin literature using *cum* and *et/atque/-que*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the beginning of Plautus's *Amphitruo* (so a bit pre-Classical), spoken by Mercurius, god of messages and commerce:

> Ut vos in vostris voltis mercimoniis
> emundis vendundis**que** me laetum lucris
> afficere **atque** adjuvare in rebus omnibus,
> **et** ut res rationes**que** vostrorum omnium
> bene expedire voltis peregri**que et** domi,
> bono**que** **atque** amplo auctare perpetuo lucro
> quas**que** incepistis res quas**que** inceptabitis,
> **et** uti bonis vos vostros**que** omnis nuntiis
> me afficere voltis…

> *As all of you want me to cause great gain in the buying **and** (que) selling of your goods, **and** (atque) help in all affairs, **and** (et) as you want me to advance your dealings **and** (que) plans, both abroad **and** (que-et) at home, **and** (atque) to increase with good **and** (que) vast eternal profits all the things you've started **and** (que-que) will start, **and** (et) as you want me to bring about good news for you **and** (que) yours, every one of them…*

From this, it seems like *et* has the broadest scope, *que* the narrowest, with *atque* in the middle.

After this there are three more *et*s in the sentence, one joining participles, one joining nouns, and one joining adjectives, and all without any other "levels" of conjunctions in the same phrase. So it does seem to be about the "nesting", not about the parts of speech they're joining.

Comment: Note, I can translate out the rest of the sentence if it would be useful; it's just a lot of text without many conjunctions to show off.

Comment: Thanks! So you'd say that my option 2 is valid for this purpose?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Definitely; I'm not sure if this is a universal "hierarchy" or just in Plautus, but it seems certainly to be precedent for that usage.

Comment: @Draconis: The English translation displays the ugly repetition of "and"; is that why three versions of this were used? Why have Mercury speaking in this way, was it a satire?

Comment: @tony I'm sure there was some humor intended, given that it's Plautus, but I don't know if it was satire directed at anyone in particular.